# Glassfish requires a new jmx role for java mission control

Tags: glassfish, jmx, java-mission-control

I have been trying out java mission control's flight recording feature with glassfish 3.1.2.2 but having been facing issues in connecting to the remote jvm using jmx.

[By default glassfish starts a JMXConnector](https://blogs.oracle.com/prsad/entry/connecting_securely_to_glassfish_via) listening at a preconfigured port - 8686. We could connect to this port from jconsole/jvisualvm using the admin console's username/password.

Adding a JVM Connection in java mission control fails when we specify the jmx details using this username/password. To make a successful connection, one has to specify a custom management.properties file as -Dcom.sun.management.config.file. To this properties file we need to specify a new jmx port, a new jmxremote.access and a new jmxremote.password file. The access and password files define new jmx role. The JVM connection on JMC can then be made with the new jmx role.

Can someone throw some light on to why the JVM connection does not work with the default username/password?

Thanks!

Comment: Trying to look into this in the JMC forum: https://community.oracle.com/message/12908196